# DataTables and Ajax using Error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: ajax, datatables

I am trying to use dataTable to populate my table but I am getting the following error.

```
"jquery.dataTables.min.js:49 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
```

I have read many posts regarding this subject but I can't see where I am going wrong.

The table

```
<table name="timeline" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped" 
    id="wayfinderSignageTable" style="width:100%" data-role="datatable" data-info="false">
  <thead>
  <tr class="CenterHeader">
    <th>Wayfinder</th>
    <th>Promotion</th>
    <th>From</th>
    <th>To</th>
    <th>RecordID</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ajax call

```
$(document).on("click", "#current_signage_data_modal", function() { 
  $('#open_current_signage_data_modal').modal('show');

  $('#wayfinderSignageTable').DataTable({
    ordering: false,
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    bInfo : false,
    responsive: true,
    fixedHeader: true,
    ajax: 'get_wayfinder_signage.php', 
    type: 'POST',
    columns: [
      { data: 'DisplayName', width: 50 },
      { data: 'Promotion', width: 50 },
      { data: 'RoomFromDate', width: 50 },
      { data: 'RoomToDate',  width: 50},
      { data: 'RecordID',  width: 50}
    ],
  });

});
```

Returned JSON

```
[{"RecordID":"104","DisplayName":"Main reception","Promotion":"EXBHX Test 1","RoomFromDate":"20-09-2019","RoomToDate":"30-09-2019"},
{"RecordID":"105","DisplayName":"Main reception","Promotion":"EXBHX Test3","RoomFromDate":"20-09-2019","RoomToDate":"30-09-2019"},
{"RecordID":"106","DisplayName":"Conference centre","Promotion":"EXBHX Test 4","RoomFromDate":"20-09-2019","RoomToDate":"30-09-2019"},
{"RecordID":"107","DisplayName":"Conference centre","Promotion":"EXBHX Test 4","RoomFromDate":"20-09-2019","RoomToDate":"30-09-2019"}]
```

Comment: @wazz Hi, what was the edit you made?

Comment: Just formatting the html table i think, to remove horizontal scroll.

Comment: Btw, I think there are some question on SO about this, but I'm not exactly sure what the problem is. My first guess is it's related to the popup, but really not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### CAUSE

Errors Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference (IE) or Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (other browsers) with jQuery DataTables usually means that the plugin cannot access the data in response from Ajax request.

#### SOLUTION

Use [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option and set it to empty string as shown below to match your JSON response.

```
$('#wayfinderSignageTable').DataTable({
   ajax: {
      url: 'get_wayfinder_signage.php', 
      dataSrc: ''
   },
   // .. skipped
});
```

#### LINKS

[jQuery DataTables: Common JavaScript console errors - TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-common-javascript-console-errors/#typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined)

Comment: @DCJones, thanks! As a side note, you should be moving `type: "POST"` under `ajax` property.